# CSS: Change font color based on current color

Tags: html, css, text, colors

I'm trying to find css that will allow me to change the color of text depending on the current color of the text.

Here is the HTML (*not HTML5*) I'm trying to change:

```
    <a href="link"><font color="green">2</font></a>
    <a href="link"><font color="red">3</font></a>
    <a href="link"><font color="red">2</font></a>
    <a href="link"><font color="green">3</font></a>
    <a href="link"><font color="red">2</font></a>
    <a href="link"><font color="green">3</font></a>
```

What I want to do is change to red links to yellow and the green links to blue. I can't use javascript or change the HTML code. I'm only allowed to add CSS to change styles. Is there a way to do this using only CSS.

Comment: Side note, the `<font>` was deprecated back around the Clinton administration.

Comment: font tag has been depricated long long ago

Comment: Here is the w3schools page in relation with j08691's statement
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

The `font` tag was **deprecated** in *HTML 4.01* and is **not supported** in *HTML5*

Comment: Ok, we all know that `font` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
a font[color="red"] { color: yellow; }
a font[color="green"] { color: blue; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zLfb/

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted to begin with. The question was "without changing the html". So even if the font tag is deprecated this shouldn't have been downvoted (of course it is noteworthy that font is deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried something similar to this, but I wasn't sure exactly how to do it and I was having a hard time finding it.